# SQL Server database migration issues

Tags: sql-server, migration, mirroring, archive

I have a system with two servers and three client workstations. Servers were configured to work as principal/mirror servers (mirroring was configured with certificates). I have two databases in SQL Server - Archive - database where we store all measurements from system and Process database.

There was a need to move Archive database from disk C: do disk D: because of low diskspace. I never really worked with SQL databases so I executed this by following the steps from this [link](https://www.sqlshack.com/move-sql-database-files-mdf-ldf-another-location/).

Everything seemed fine on principal server - I was getting all data from Archive database, but on the mirror server I noticed that mirroring was suspended (for both databases). I stopped mirroring and tried to set it up again with command set partner first on mirror then on principal. Command was successfully completed on mirror but on principal I got following error:

> Msg 1499, Level 16, State 1, Line 1; Database mirroring error: status 1460, severity 16, state 1, string Archive.*

Do you know what can cause this and how can I resolve this issue? When I moved database, I changed user for SQL Server service from NT Service/MSSQLSERVER to Local system on both servers.

Second problem: When I try to access measurements in Archive database from client workstations (through SCADA application) all values are displayed as 0. But when I try to access Archive from server PC, all values are correctly displayed. I even tried moving database back to disk C: and changed SQL Server service user back to NT Service/MSSQLSERVER but the issue remained the same. Also I noticed that .mdf file did not grow in four days (not even a little bit), but I don't understand how can I get readings from server PC for those days if nothing was written to database.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which version and edition of SQL Server?

Comment: @J.D. SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition.